# Craftyjs scene size

Tags: javascript, craftyjs

I'm working with crafty on a game with an open world and i want to use the full window screen.
But when i start the game, the scene is not the full width.
I have tried:
`Crafty.init(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);`
`Crafty.viewport.init(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);`
It seems that it takes the biggest sprite width & height and uses that.
But when i try to create a bigger rectangle so it would use that, it still uses that sprites' height & width

`Crafty.canvas.init(..)` seems to create a new canvas.

How do i create a full size canvas-scene in crafty?

Comment: How do you know it only uses the sprite's height?

Comment: srry, it also uses it's width (edited)

Comment: Still, how can you tell? Are you using a red border or the development tools or alert?

Comment: because i use a background has the exact same size as the canvas,
but i found the answer: i edited the crafty library and saw they use the Crafty.DOM.window.width/height but if i use window.innerWidht/Height it is fixed

Comment: I suggest you post the code as an answer so the next person can see the solution easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In crafty 0.5.4 in the Crafty.viewport.init() function, the width and height of crafty is initialized as:
`this.width = (!w ? w : Crafty.DOM.width (something like that))`

same for height

Change Crafty.DOM.width to window.innerWidth and it is fixed

**PS.** Crafty 0.6(beta) solves this too.